Any info on Kotzk/Przysucha Hasidut
בס״ד
Shalom aleychum!
I recently found out I descend from Kotzker Hasidim and I wanted to know if anyone knows what continuation there is today/what's the closest Hasidic group to it? As well as any other info.
שכויח

The Biala-Jerusalem Hasidut seems to be a direct surviving continuation of the Przysucha. The wikipedia page shows that there were several parallel dynasties continuing the tradition, some of which did not survive WW2.
The Kotzk Hasidut continues in Bnei Brak as can be seen at their wikipedia page.
There are certainly many editions of sefarim explaining the thought of these chassidic groups in Hebrew which you may find in various Jewish bookstores and internet sites.
If you would like to read in English, you might enjoy the following books:

"Quest for Authenticity: The Thought of Reb Simhah Bunim" by Michael Rosen
"Leaping Souls: Rabbi Menachem Mendel and the Spirit of Kotzk" by Chaim Feinberg
"Jewish Wisdom for Daily Life: Sayings of Rabbi Menahem Mendl of Kotzk" by Miriam Chaikin and Gabriel Lisowski


I have read Quest for Authenticity: The Thought of Reb Simhah Bunim and it really shows how Przysucha Hasidus has a very different mindset, much more challenging than some.

@Mike yes. The founders of those hassidic movements were giants who brought great ideas.
